# SAM AWS Lambda Python: gateway api - handle binary form upload

Tags: aws-lambda, sam

SAM AWS Lambda Python: I create a function that receive a file with `multipart/form-data`

but when I send the following request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://....execute-api.....amazonaws.com/Prod/ocrReceipt' \
--header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
--header 'Pragma: no-cache' \
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
--header 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
--header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8' \
--form 'file=@"/D:/receipt.png"'
```

I get the event with missing `Content-Length` and `"isBase64Encoded": false`

and my code fail because I do `fp = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(body))  # decode`

when I access the same function with the `Function URL`  I don't get this error (i.e. `Content-Length` is set and `"isBase64Encoded": true`

How can I config the gateway api to accept `multipart/form-data` properly?

I tried to set `multipart/form-data` and `multipart/*` in `API > Settings > Binary Media Types`
but it doesn't help

[image]

Not that is says `You can configure binary support for your API by specifying which media types should be treated as binary types. API Gateway will look at the Content-Type and Accept HTTP headers to decide how to handle the body.`

Did I set the correct value?

Can I fix it by some setting in the SAM template?

Event:

```
{"resource": "/ocrReceipt", "path": "/ocrReceipt", "httpMethod": "POST", "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8", "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https", "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true", "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false", "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false", "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false", "CloudFront-Viewer-ASN": "1680", "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "IL", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------592233465752962090703619", "Host": "6y5o0gb78g.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com", "Origin": "https://doc2txt.com", "Postman-Token": "f39dea09-b71f-47bb-aa8a-57783df2ddf1", "Pragma": "no-cache", "Referer": "https://doc2txt.com/", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36", "Via": "1.1 759e09affff41285e9585e1a31532bd4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)", "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "5jCh7W91ayJWUf_75DfWr-IfCj2CvCobvTlshBjoqaElhVWsNmlFuA==", "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-63b7df99-5a343d1a16ca5cde72a47d66", "X-Forwarded-For": "176.12.157.166, 130.176.1.83", "X-Forwarded-Port": "443", "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"}, "multiValueHeaders": {"Accept": ["application/json, text/plain, */*"], "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate, br"], "Accept-Language": ["en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8"], "Cache-Control": ["no-cache"], "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"], "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": ["true"], "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": ["false"], "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": ["false"], "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": ["false"], "CloudFront-Viewer-ASN": ["1680"], "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": ["IL"], "Content-Type": ["multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------592233465752962090703619"], "Host": ["6y5o0gb78g.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com"], "Origin": ["https://doc2txt.com"], "Postman-Token": ["f39dea09-b71f-47bb-aa8a-57783df2ddf1"], "Pragma": ["no-cache"], "Referer": ["https://doc2txt.com/"], "User-Agent": ["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"], "Via": ["1.1 759e09affff41285e9585e1a31532bd4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"], "X-Amz-Cf-Id": ["5jCh7W91ayJWUf_75DfWr-IfCj2CvCobvTlshBjoqaElhVWsNmlFuA=="], "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": ["Root=1-63b7df99-5a343d1a16ca5cde72a47d66"], "X-Forwarded-For": ["176.12.157.166, 130.176.1.83"], "X-Forwarded-Port": ["443"], "X-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"]}, "queryStringParameters": null, "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null, "pathParameters": null, "stageVariables": null, "requestContext": {"resourceId": "7g6rs7", "resourcePath": "/ocrReceipt", "httpMethod": "POST", "extendedRequestId": "eT_iDFWXCGYFfyQ=", "requestTime": "06/Jan/2023:08:45:26 +0000", "path": "/Prod/ocrReceipt", "accountId": "899418482974", "protocol": "HTTP/1.1", "stage": "Prod", "domainPrefix": "6y5o0gb78g", "requestTimeEpoch": 1672994726594, "requestId": "8a23ce92-11fe-4e54-bbb0-5ad355130833", "identity": {"cognitoIdentityPoolId": null, "accountId": null, "cognitoIdentityId": null, "caller": null, "sourceIp": "176.12.157.166", "principalOrgId": null, "accessKey": null, "cognitoAuthenticationType": null, "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null, "userArn": null, "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36", "user": null}, "domainName": "6y5o0gb78g.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com", "apiId": "6y5o0gb78g"}, "body": "...", "isBase64Encoded": false}
```

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.8

  Sample SAM Template for ocrSam

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128

Resources:
  Doc2txtFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      Timeout: 60
      Role: arn:aws:iam::899418482974:role/service-role/ocrReceipt-role-v2edsg0i
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Doc2txt:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /ocrReceipt
            Method: ANY

    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./doc2txt
      DockerTag: python3.8-v1

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  Doc2txtApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Doc2txt function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/ocrReceipt/"
  Doc2txtFunction:
    Description: "Doc2txt Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt Doc2txtFunction.Arn
  Doc2txtFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Doc2txt function"
    Value: arn:aws:iam::899418482974:role/service-role/ocrReceipt-role-v2edsg0i #!GetAtt Doc2txtFunctionRole.Arn
```

EDIT:
I was able to get `"isBase64Encoded": true` with the following:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - "*/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get "isBase64Encoded": true with the following:

```yaml
    Globals:
      Api:
        BinaryMediaTypes:
          - "*/*"
```

apparently the `content-lenght` is not necessary, so I just remove it from the code:

```js
    headers = {
        "content-type": headers["Content-Type"],
        # "content-length": headers["Content-Length"],
    }
    fs = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=fp, environ=environ, headers=headers)
```